# Как работать с полем типа DateTime в MSSQL через JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Есть таблица в которой содержится поле типа DateTime в котором хронится дата и время некой операции. При запросе через MS SQL Manager я вижу что есть записи даты со временем.
При запросе через JDBC, при вызове следующих методов: **getDate() и getTimeStamp()** мне прилетает только дата с нулевым временем ( *я проверял что именно дата без временем, преобразуя дату в секунды*). При вызове getTime() мне прилетает дата 1 января 1970 года (что правильно) и 0 часов 0 мину 0 секунд.
При работе с Oracle или MySQL таких граблей ней. Метод getDate() возвращает и дату и время..

Comment: @Alex78191 там надо выгружать большое количество записей и терять время на преобразование из даты в строку и обратно не хочелось бы

Comment: jdbc драйвер тоже время теряет на преобразование.

Comment: @Alex78191 а как тогда лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, у вас есть приложение Java, которое использует драйвер JDBC Microsoft SQL Server версии 3.0 и Java Runtime Environment версии 1.7 (JRE 1.7) для подключения к базе данных SQL Server. Драйвер некорректно работает с JRE > 1.6.

Если это сценарий, это может быть вызвано драйверами JDBC. Исправление для этого доступно по ссылке ниже:

[Исправление](http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2652061&kbln=en-us)

Лучшая практика заключается в том, чтобы взять то, что дает ваш драйвер JDBC, и от этого создавать объекты  Java 8, java.time. *. В конце концов, должны выйти новые драйверы JDBC, которые автоматически будут использовать новые классы java.time. *. До тех пор некоторые методы были добавлены к классам `java.sql.*`, чтобы взаимодействовать с java.time, например, `toInstant` и `toLocalDateTime` в Timestamp. `java.sql.date` содержит только дату без времени.

Comment: Как я обожаю MS который выкладывают такие исправления в exe :). Сейчас под Linux буду wine ставить что бы разархивировать это добро. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @plesser Exe нужно запускать на Windows, зачем Linux?

Comment: потому что сейчас у меня под рукой только линукс, предварительно протестировать я сейчас могу только с него. Завтра уже буду окончательно тестировать с винды

Comment: @plesser исправление есть и в `tar.gz` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2652061/fix-sql-server-jdbc-driver-3.0-returns-incorrect-date-values-when-used-with-jre-1.7-by-a-java-application

Comment: мне ссылку на zip-exe прислали. Я уже разархивировал

Comment: @plesser действительно

Comment: помогло, правда все равно пришлось извращаться. getDate() возвращает только дату но getTime стал возвращать время и заработал getTimestamp. Спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: @plesser `java.sql.Date` предназначен для предоставления только даты без времени http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html. ты же в SQL server в тип date не можешь время записать. Для этого как раз тип timestamp существует.

Comment: а смысл тогда например в таком конструкторе : public Date(long date). И в описании по приведенной тобой ссылки я не где не нашел упоминания только дата. И потом the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

Comment: @plesser написано дата будет нормализована удалением информации о времени. Почитай, что это конструктор делает http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(long)

Comment: zero не заметил.... Вы правы а я не прав

Comment: @plesser Я еще ответ обновил

Comment: аха, большое спасибо